# Cookie consent and Google Identity Services to log users in

Tags: cookies, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

I've been trying to find a straight answer to this to no avail.

If you use Google Identity Services to authenticate users on a site, what are your responsibilities in relation to listing and allowing users to accept / rejecect the Google cookies that are created in the user's browser as a result of using this auth method.

Furthermore, is there a cookie consent management service which accomodates requirements relating to these cookies.

Thanks,